# Inconsistent accessibility: property type in DbContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have added Dbset in Context i.e.

```
 public Dbset<Demo> Demo{ get; set; }
```

but I am getting compilation error here i.e.

```
Error   1   Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MVC.Model.Demo>' is less accessible than property 'MVC.Model.Demo'  D:Files/project 210 34  MVC.Data
```

Here is my Model:-

```
class Demo
    {
        [Key]
        [Display(Name = "ID", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        public long Id { get; set;}

        [Display(Name = "CountryID", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        public long CountryId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "RightID", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        public long RightId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Amount", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        public double Amount { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`Demo` has no access modifier and classes are `internal` by default, so it is less accessible than the `DbSet` `Demo` which is `public`. Also, you should probably call the `DbSet` `Demos` so as not to confuse the two and since semantically it holds a set of Demos.

Since the set is public:

```
 public DbSet<Demo> Demo { get; set; }
```

You need to make the Demo class public as well:

```
public class Demo
{
     ....
}
```

As mentioned, I also suggest you change the set to:

```
public DbSet<Demo> Demos { get; set; }
```

so that you don't confuse the set with the class type.

Comment: If I am removing "public" from the above code then it gets compiled successfully but then I am not able to access Allocation Model from controller page. So what to do for that?

Comment: @user3206357 - you need to make Allocation public.

Comment: @user3206357 - great.

Comment: I always seem to forget this… Is there a reason why the creation of a class doesn’t include the `public` automagically? Or is it just a simple oversight, where M$ assumes you’ll remember to do this every time, or omits it for lowest common denominator reasons?

Comment: @RenéKåbis - M$ probably chose private to be the default so that your classes wouldn't be externally available by default. You need to specifically make them so. It is a case of the doors being closed until you specifically open then.

Answer (score 2):

you should make your model public,
so just change it to

```
public class Demo{}
```